# APEX webservice invoke receiving empty soap resulting in error

Tags: apex, soap

I'm having an issue with consuming an SAP PI webservice in salesforce:
For calling the webservice I'm using the Webservice.invoke(...)-Method.

Problem: The webservice is returning an empty soap body in case of success.
Seems like salesforce can't handle this properly.

Basically the question is what to put in for the question marks.

```
WebServiceCallout.invoke(
            this,
            request_x,
            response_map_x,
            new String[]{endpoint_x,
                'http://sap.com/xi/WebService/soap1.1',
                'http://companyXY.com/xi/Inbound/Orders',
                'xyzabc',
                'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/',
                'Body',
                '???'}                    
        );
```

Kind regards,
Max

Comment: Related: [Error while getting response in SOAP Webservice Integration](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/45492/102)

Comment: Can you share the WSDL? What does the WSDL indicate the response should be?

Comment: That's the main problem:
The WSDL isn't stating any response type. The guy who is responsible for the webservice also stated that an empty response is the expected result.

So this:
`<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP:Header/>
   <SOAP:Body/>
</SOAP:Envelope>`

is the expected result that I'm actually receiving.

Comment: You  might need to make a direct Apex HTTP post as I don't thing WebServiceCallout.invoke can handle a method with no response.
See the [FuseIT version of wsdl2apex](http://www.fishofprey.com/2014/11/dreamforce-2014-presentation-improved.html)

Comment: That's what I already feared.
Still trying to fix it on webservice side,
but wanted to check all possibilities with WebServiceCallout.invoke beforehand.

Thanks anyway!